# Replacing all overlapping patterns in a string

Tags: string, python-2.7, replace, substitution

Given the string: `s = "101010101"`, I would like to replace every occurrence of the pattern `010`, with the pattern `0X0`, so that the result should be `s = "10X0X0X01"`.

Another similar problem is to replace the same pattern `010` with `00`, so that the resulting string should be `s = 100001`.

So far, I tried by:

```
import re
s = "101010101"
s = re.sub("010", "0X0", s)
```

but the resulting string is `10X010X01`, missing to replace the `1` in the middle.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to find values without including them in the match:

```
s = re.sub(r"(?<=0)1(?=0)", "X", s)
```

`(?<=0)1(?=0)` matches a single `1` character that is preceded – `(?<=…)` –
 and followed – `(?=…)` – by a zero.

Comment: Great! What about the problem of replacing `010` with `00`?

Comment: @Ale: `"X"` → `""`

Comment: Yes, I've just realized it.

Answer (score -1):

Almost all string manipulation problems can be solved with regex. That doesn't mean you should use them. This seems like a natural problem to use regex for, but you don't *really* need it. You can just strip the leading/trailing 1s, then replace the 1s in the middle, then put the leading/trailing 1s back on:

```
s = "101010101"
s = "1" + s[1:-1].replace("1", "X") + "1"

print s
```

outputs: `10X0X0X01`

```
s = "101010101"
s = "1" + s[1:-1].replace("1", "") + "1"

print s
```

outputs: `100001`

I think what you'll find is that regex are extremely powerful, but virtually unreadable and hard to reason about. Take your question, for example. What you did looks like it would work to someone not experience with regex, but it doesn't.

It's a tradeoff, but simplicity always wins in my book.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, but it seems to be too much specific. In fact the question is about replacing overlapping patterns. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not sure it deserved the downvote, though. It does answer this (specific) question.

Comment: Didn't mean to make it sound like you did! I wish the downvoter would explain what they don't like, though...